# How to Queue a Build Using Azure DevOps REST API in Python?

Tags: post, build, parameters, azure-devops, python-requests

I want to be able to queue an Azure DevOps build using python.

I have the following code:

```
params_dict = {
        "id" : [Build ID #]
    }

url = "https://dev.azure.com/[my_organization]/[my_project]/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1"

requests.post(url, json = params_dict, auth=(username, password))
```

However, when I run this code, I get:

```
{'$id': '1',
 'errorCode': 0,
 'eventId': 0,
 'innerException': None,
 'message': 'Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: build.Definition',
 'typeKey': 'ArgumentNullException',
 'typeName': 'System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib'}
```

I've tried using `build.Definition` in the params_dict, `definition`, etc. No permutation seems to work. I get the same error for them all.

What key do I need to give in my params_dict to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error, I figured out the correct format for the params_dict is:

```
params_dict = {
    "definition": {
        "id": [Build ID #]
    } 
}
```

Using this dictionary, the build successfully queues.